# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation') react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Stack Navigator in React Native App. I have a problem with the navigation props.

Here is my component where I call my navigate method.

```
class CommandsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }


    addCommand(){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("CreateCommand");
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
                <MyList itemsUrl="http://localhost:9000/commands"/>
                <Button title="Ajouter" onPress={this.addCommand}></Button>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

export default StackNavigator({
    CommandsList : {
        screen : CommandsList,
    },
});
```

And my App.js

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        CommandsList: {
            screen: CommandsList,
        },
        CreateCommand: {
            screen: CreateCommand,
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'CommandsList'
    }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <RootStack/>;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I have an error on navigate methods. :/

Comment: add `navigate` at `App.js` so the import should `import { StackNavigator, navigation} from 'react-navigation';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your reference either using `bind` in the constructor or by using the `fat arrow` function to reference `this` to the `context`

```
addCommand = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("CreateCommand");
}
```

or

```
constructor() {
   super()
   this.addCommand = this.addCommand.bind(this);
}
```

Also you may check this [article](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=6%20ways%20to%20bind%20react&oq=6%20ways%20to%20bind%20react&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.4422j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)