# this._fetchData(page) is not a function? why?

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I *'up-slide refreshing'* to load more data, I get the following error:

> `this._fetchData(page) is not a function?`

Below is the code I'm using:

```js
componentDidMount(){
    this._fetchData(1)
}

//请求数据
_fetchData(page) {
    const that = this

    //如果页数不为零,则修改上滑isLoadingData的state为true;
    //否则就修改下拉刷新isRefreshing的state为true
    if(page !== 0){
        this.setState({
            isLoadingData: true
        })
    }else{
        this.setState({
            isRefreshing: true
        })
    } 
    try {
        //request.get('http://www.rapapi.org/mockjs/33254/api/list?accessToken=labike&page=10')
        request.get(Config.api.baseUrl + Config.api.list, {
            accessToken: 'labike',
            page: page
        }) 
}

_fetchMoreData(){
    // if(!this._hasMoreData || this.state.isLoadingData){
    //     return
    // }
    const page = cacleResult.nextPage
    console.log(page)
    this._fetchData(page)
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Header</Text>
            </View>
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this._renderItem}
                renderFooter={this._renderFooter}
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
                        tintColor="#ff0000"
                        title="Loading..."
                    />
                }
                onEndReached={this._fetchMoreData}
                onEndReachedThreshold={20}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                enableEmptySections={true}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where's your ```catch```?

Comment: yeah, it is not complete code , look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853736/how-to-resolve-react-native-loadingmoredata-doesnt-working

Comment: help me, where not load more data? thanks!

Comment: did you bind your methods? can you paste the whole class code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853736/how-to-resolve-react-native-loadingmoredata-doesnt-working @ Prince Hernandez

Comment: @PrinceHernandez   this is my whole code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853736/how-to-resolve-react-native-loadingmoredata-doesnt-working

Comment: `_fetchData = (page) => {`,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856497/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigation-react-navigation/49856554?noredirect=1#comment86727552_49856554

Comment: i am try _fetchData = （page）=> ｛｝but  also get this error

Comment: @PritishVaidya becase of _fetchData is not component bind method，it is me defined get data method ，so can’t  bind this in constructor

Comment: @PritishVaidya becase of _fetchData is not component bind method，it is me defined get data method ，so can’t  bind this in constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not binding your methods to the `this` of your class. change your constructor to be like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
        isLoadingData: false,
        isRefreshing: false
    }

    this._fetchData = this._fetchData.bind(this);
    this._fetchMoreData = this._fetchMoreData.bind(this);
}
```

this should solve the problem.